# How do I check package version for a given distribution version from the cli?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Related: [How do I check package version using apt-get / aptitude?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/how-do-i-check-package-version-using-apt-get-aptitude)

How do I do this for a given variable debian release, from the command line? Using either apt, dpkg, or aptitude is fine.
Ideally, relying on the packages.debian.org website is *not* ok as the requested release may be out of date. (The ftp archive does contain the older releases).

E.g.:

```
release="bullseye"
package="wget"
version=$(some_magic_apt_command $release)
echo $version

1.21-1+deb11u1

release="stretch"
package="wget"
version=$(some_magic_apt_command $release)
echo $version

1.18-5+deb9u3
```

I also need to know which 'repository' it's from. Main, contrib, or nonfree?

```
release="stretch"
package="wget"
type=$(some_magic_apt_command $release)
echo $type

main
```

Requirements:

- It has to work for **any release: not just the current installed version**.

Purpose:

Extracting old packages to find original configuration files that have changed, not remembering what was changed, to figure out how to update these config files for a newer version (the question: *what did the programmers change about the config files, it's undocumented*).

Comment: If you don't have an installation, but also can't rely on central debian package archives, where would the information magically come from?

Comment: You can use the central archive. Just don't use/scrape the http/html website. The website will only keep the last 2-3 stable versions. The repositories go back much further.

Answer (score 0):

so, then the answer seems to be: simply have a podman container for each release, and ask dpkg inside each of them;

One-time setup on your host (Deb 11) machine:

```
sudo apt install -y podman
sudo usermod --add-subuids 100000-165535 --add-subgids 100000-165535 YOURUSERNAMEHERE
```

from thereon to check `PKG` on `DEBIAN_RELEASE`:

```
DEBIAN_RELEASE=8
PKG=gnuradio
podman run \
       -it \
       --rm \
       "debian:${DEBIAN_RELEASE}" \
       sh -c "apt-get update; apt-cache show \"${PKG}\"" \
| grep 'Version:'
```

For debians prior to – I think – 7 you might need to adjust the URLS in /etc/apt/sources.list first, but you could either just do that in the command passed via `sh -c`, or first build an image where that's already done and replace `debian:releasenumber` with that.